# Save answers as draft

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, stackexchange

I am only active in SO and Code Review, and I find that Code Review answers can take a bit of time, especially when fiddling around with a Plunker or JSFiddle sample or finding some reference as to why one approach is generally accepted to be better than another approach.

Right now, I actually keep a sticky open on my desktop with my review and copy/paste when it is ready. I would love Stack Exchange (or just Code Review) to have a '(auto) Save as Draft' feature so that I don't need the sticky anymore.

Your thoughts?

Edit : Apparently this already works, to be tested.

Comment: It **does** save as draft..... every 30 seconds or so, if I am not mistaken....

Comment: More info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer that I may want to come back to.... I started it at noon, and now that I look at it, there's a spot above this box that says 'Your Answer'. And, occasionally, above that it pops up and says 'draft saved'......

yea, I typed the above text, and then closed the window, opened it up again, browsed to this post, and **voila!** there it is again....